# What is the default servlet for mapping with undefined servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a Servlet mapping in my application with out a servlet defined for it.

Eclipse produces a warning on it:

```
The servlet mapping "/docs/*" refers to a servlet that is not defined
```

> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/docs/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

There is no defined servlet default. But it is only a warrning, the application itself works fine and serves content from that url pattern.

Is there a "default" servlet that handles those servlet mappings? if not? how does this even work?

**Additional Info**

I have another mapping like so and it has a servlet:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
```

> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

So to Kayaman's answer. if i remove the "redundant" mapping. the /docs functionality stops working.

what i actually want is to know what servlet is the default one so i can create a servlet for my mapping and avoid the warnings.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to declare this `servlet-mapping` if there is no servlet?! Why not simply avoid the declaration?

Comment: See my additional info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle docs:

> Each Web application has a default servlet. This default servlet can be a servlet that you specify, or, if you do not specify a default servlet, WebLogic Server uses an internal servlet called the FileServlet as the default servlet.
>
> You can register any servlet as the default servlet. Writing your own default servlet allows you to use your own logic to decide how to handle a request that falls back to the default servlet.

[Setting Up a Default Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html#wp157934)

[Tomcat Specific](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/default-servlet.html#what)

Comment: TY for the answer. so is there a way to get rid of the eclipse warning? any chance i can call the servlet-name of the FileServlet?

Comment: Actually the answer is at the "Tomcat Specific" documentation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default servlet that handles static data is being used. You've made a servlet mapping, but you're essentially just using the default HTTP server-like behaviour of the servlet container.

It's unnecessary.